# what's the purpose of `producer.disconnect or `consumer.disconnect` in kafkajs?

Tags: kafkajs

what's the purpose of the `disconnect` functions in kafkajs?

```js
const producer = kafka.producer()

await producer.connect()
await producer.send({
  topic: 'test-topic',
  messages: [
    { value: 'Hello KafkaJS user!' },
  ],
})

await producer.disconnect()
```

what happens if I don't call it at the end of my program?

is it only a flush / memory leak thing or does it impact the kafka side as well?

couldn't find any description of it in the kafkajs docs.

Comment: it is funny that there is no clear answer about this even in google